# Insert new line after all occurrences of a pattern

Tags: shell-script, sed, xml

I have a pmml file containing one line:

```
<DataField dataType="string" name="class" optype="categorical"><Value value="y0" /><Value value="y1" /><Value value="y2" /><Value value="y3" /><Value value= "y4" /></DataField><DataField dataType="double" name="x0" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x1" optype= "continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x2" optype="continuo    us" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x3" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x4" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x5" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x6" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x7" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x8" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x9" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x10" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x11" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x12" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x13" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x14" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x15" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x16" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x17" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x18"     optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x19" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x20" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x21" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x22" optype="continuous" /><DataField dataType="double" name="x23" optype="continuous" /></DerivedField></NeuralOutput></NeuralOutputs></NeuralNetwork></PMML>
```

I want to insert a new line after all of the  `optype= "continuous" />` occurrences.

I was able to inset the new line between the first `optype` and the last `/>` using `sed 's:optype.*/>:a&\n:g' test.pmml > new.pmml`.

How can I do this for all occurrences of the pattern? (I prefer sed but solutions using other tools are fine as well.)

Comment: Have you tried formatting the file with tools like xmlstarlet or xml tidy?  Because I assume this is a question about formatting of XML.

Comment: No I haven't, I will give them a try. However, it would be nice to know the answer assuming it is not a pmml or those tools not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this with GNU `sed` or other `sed` implementations that now also treat `\n` as newline in the replacement:

```
sed 's|optype[^>]*/>|&\n|g' test.pmml
```

POSIXly:

```
sed 's|optype[^>]*/>|&\
|g' test.pmml
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to nicely format your XML file, then something like [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) can do this for you:

```
xmlstarlet fo file.xml >new-file.xml
```

The fact that your XML file is a `pmml` file should not matter as long as `pmml` is an XML format.

XMLStarlet is a general XML tool for performing XPATH queries etc., but there are also tools specifically for formatting XML documents, such as [`Tidy`](https://xmlwriter.net/user_tools/tidy.shtml).